# Copy a value to another StatefulWidget

Tags: string, flutter, dart, statefulwidget

I tried to rebuild the code of this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d5PpeNb-dOY) 
, which is about how to copy a `String` value to another `StatefulWidget`, but now I get the `BodyConstructionState(value)` **red underlined** and it says "**Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.**" `Value` comes from another widget. I don´t know why because I did it in the same way like the guy in the video did it. Can anybody tell me what my mistake is? Thanks in advance!

```
class BodyConstruction extends StatefulWidget {

      String value;
      BodyConstruction({Key key, @required this.value}) : super(key : key);


      @override
      _BodyConstructionState createState() => _BodyConstructionState(value);
    }

    class _BodyConstructionState extends State<BodyConstruction> {

      String value;
      _BodyConstructionState({this.value});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are creating an object of `BodyContruction`, you are supposed to do this

```
BodyConstruction object = new BodyConstruction(value: "Some Value");
```

and not

```
BodyConstruction object = new BodyConstruction("Some Value");
```

Creating a constructor parameter with `{}` makes them named optional parameters.

Note: `new` keyboard is optional in Dart.

Answer (score 0):

This would work perfectly. Check it out.

```
   // declare a body construction object
   BodyConstruction _bodyConstruction;

   // initialise the object declared above
   _bodyConstruction = BodyConstruction(value: 'Your Value');
```

Note: When `{}` is used in a constructor or method body, it denotes a named parameter. Check the official documentation for more explanation.

[Click here to read more on named parameters in Flutter](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#functions)